# Should we add a "gender" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

On [Transgender in the UK, should I use my female name on my CV even when it refers to male accomplishments?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30846/transgender-in-the-uk-should-i-use-my-female-name-on-my-cv-even-when-it-refers), we had several comments about users trying to find similar questions about the specific challenges with gender identity issues in the workplace.

I found these two other questions which would be an ideal fit for this tag

- [What are tools/resources I can use to check a company for transphobia and sexism during a job search?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27403/what-are-tools-resources-i-can-use-to-check-a-company-for-transphobia-and-sexism/27407)
- [When to let potential empoyers know I'm trans?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30590/when-to-let-potential-empoyers-know-im-trans)

but can't seem to find any others through searching.

A dedicated tag would group these questions for the benefit of interested experts and visitors alike.

I am not sure what exactly is needed to justify a new tag (or even what the ideal naming of the tag should be), but was interested on the community's thoughts on this.

Edit: to avoid an explosion of tiny, very specific tags without many questions, we could use a more umbrella term, such as gender (as suggested by Adrian), and add the very specific tags as synonyms of the larger tag (as suggested by Jmac).

Comment: Should we add a homosexual tag too? I'm being serious, because any of these questions could have simply swapped transgender for homosexual.

Comment: @Jim G perhaps they could have, but the posters asked about being transgender, not about being gay. Searching for any questions/answers with "homosexual" or "homosexuality" comes up blank. A few answers show up when searching for "gay", but those questions are not about gay individuals in the workplace.

Comment: Hi Matt, I did a very brief search earlier, and I only saw 2 or 3 relevant questions. That to me seems like there isn't enough content to justify creating a new tag. This isn't to say one can't be created, but I'm not sure there would be much benefit above and beyond simply searching the term.

Comment: If we were going to do this, to prevent having a ton of different tags, adding a generic 'sexuality' tag involving problems related to sexuality (transgender, transexual, gay, straight, asexual, etc.) may be better, and creating separate tags all synonymized to that tag (so that someone searching for 'trans' can select the proper tag). Do you think that there are significantly different issues faced by each group that would make this pointless?

Comment: @jmac: Good idea.

Comment: @jmac I think a generic umbrella tag with synonyms for the specific terms would solve the grouping issue and as jmort253 pointed out, there is not enough content to justify the separate tags. I'm still newish to workplace.se, and don't want to step on any toes, so what is the best way to proceed here? Do we need a certain number of votes or views or some other indicator that we have agreement with the community at large?

Comment: Matt, it only takes [300 reputation to create a new tag](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), and you have enough to do so. 'Sexuality' sounds like a good way to cover these until there's more content to justify more narrow tags. If you want to tag these questions, I'd say go for it.

Comment: @jmort253: I added the sexuality tag to the questions. I don't have tag synonym privileges yet, so I'm not able to suggest the specific terms as synonyms

Comment: I really appreciate the effort to make tagging more useful here, but I think "sexuality" is the wrong tag. Gender identity/expression and sexuality are very different, and I think most trans folks would not expect to find answers to their questions under a "sexuality" tag. Maybe a "gender" tag as well/instead?

Comment: (For context, I posted one of the linked questions; having it tagged "sexuality" actually bothers me a bit. Not seriously enough to dispute the tag if the community finds it useful, but enough that if it were left up to me I would untag it.)

Comment: @jmac I'd rather use wording "gender-related", it feels closer to workplace topics than "sexuality"

Comment: Hey @Matt, could you suggest a name for the tag with an [edit] to your question? Looks like 'sexuality' was tossed out. Perhaps 'gender' or 'gender-related' as suggested by gnat above? Something that makes sense and makes you feel comfortable with it.

Comment: Yeah, I just had my post edited by Matt, and while I understand they were trying to help, it feels really uncomfortable and not useful. I don't quite know what the answer is, but it's not 'sexuality'.

Comment: I definitely was not trying to make the question askers uncomfortable here, my apologies to you Adrian and @raptortech97. What is the best way to fix this? Is there a "rename" button for tags that can change it en masse or should I go back and untag those questions until we have a better term picked out?

Comment: I don't know in general, but for my question I've undone your edit. If we need to re-tag them later, we can just search for trans and transgender, which should get us all 3 posts.

Comment: @JimG. err no the isu of gender and sexual attraction is tricky

Comment: _When to let potential empoyers know I'm trans?_ : Why do you find that necessary?! Does not smell good at all IMO. Do women go around saying to people "You, know I'm a woman"? Make up your mind - if you're a woman, you're a woman, if not,then not. Sounds like you're trying to make some sort of political statement, which is not appropriate in a workplace.

Comment: @Vector, whenever you change employment, there are all sorts of official documents required, things that list your 'official' gender. If that gender does not match the gender you identify with, then it is **definitely** something that needs to be broached with employers. Women do not have ID cards that say they are a man unless they are trans-, and *that* is why this is a unique problem that merits a tag. If you strongly (and rationally) believe this tag is unnecessary, please answer the question and explain why clearly so the community can evaluate your stance.

Comment: @Vector I think it's important at some point, if for no other reason than HR may want to be aware in case they want to review their materials and policies for increased sensitivity, and be prepared for potential incidents. If you were trans, would you want your employer to be completely unprepared when an incident arises?

Comment: @jmac - I was not addressing the question of the tag at all. It can be a tag or not - I have no particular stance on that. I'm just pointing out something that hit me in the question.

Comment: @corsiKa - you are making an excellent point. Sh-t happens - good to be prepared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I have changed 'sexuality' to 'gender' as per the comments, but I think that this brings up separate problems (specifically that 'gender' will be specific to gender-related issues, and can just as easily apply to men working in a female-dominated workplace, or women working in a male-dominated workplace, as well as trans- members in various workplaces, while at the same time not covering issues related to being homosexual that aren't necessarily related to gender).

If someone could please take the time to make a good [tag wiki](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) for [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) to be clear what it should be used for, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I took a [first pass](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/gender/info) at it, but given my earlier stumbles in wording would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Looks good to me @Matt! Thanks for the work in putting that together.

Comment: jmac, were you going to add the "transgender" tag synonym to gender? Some users are using a combination of gender + transition tags to indicate it http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/inspirational-transgender-people-in-the-field-of-technology

Comment: @Matt, the synonym for transgender has been added. Trying to create a question with that tag will add 'gender' instead.