# How should questions about transgender issues be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

While tagging some questions with the [lgbtq](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq) tag, I noticed we also have the [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag.

Current description of the [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag:

> Questions relating to gender, gender identity, and being part of a workplace dominated by a different gender than one's own.

As of time of writing, the [lgbtq](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq) tag does not have a description (in fact, before I started tagging some questions with it, it only had 5 questions on it). I suggested the following (it is currently being reviewed):

> Questions specific to the lesbian, gay, bisexual, transgender and queer employees. Consider adding a location tag, since local cultural or legal norms will most likely have an impact on the answer.

Now, I realize when it comes to transgender issues, there is an overlap between these two tags. We are dealing with a question clearly part of "gender identity", but also by definition part of the LGBTQ group. So the question is how transgender issues should be tagged.

I have the following assumptions:

1. There are issues specific and common to LGBTQ employees; for example, in some jurisdictions they may be members of the same protected class. They may have issues with coming out and being harassed because of their identity. Therefore it makes sense to have a tag for them.
2. Transgender employees face some issues that LGB employees do not share.
3. The [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag has such a broad scope that it is necessary to keep it and not delete it.

So the alternatives I am seeing are the following:

1. Removing the "gender identity" aspect from the [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag, potentially necessitating retagging some questions. Tag transgender-topic questions as [lgbtq](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq).
2. Removing the "gender identity" aspect from the [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag, potentially necessitating retagging some questions. Tag transgender-topic questions as a new tag [transgender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transgender).
3. Tag transgender-topic questions with only [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) and not [lgbtq](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq). It would then be sensible to remove the "t" from the "lgbtq" tag, which, however, is completely contrary to the common usage of the acronym.

Previous discussion on the [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) tag: [Should we add a "gender" tag?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/should-we-add-a-gender-tag)

Thoughts?

Comment: I get where you are coming from, but if I were posting a question on the topic of transexualism, and I saw the description of [gender] including "Questions relating to gender", I would probably end up using the tag anyway.

Comment: If we were try to carve out gender identity from gender in general, then *don't* make the new tag "transgender".  That excludes non-binary and genderfluid and probably some other gender identities I don't know about.  I don't know if "gender-identity" would be the right tag, but it's less exclusive at least.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I don't see any issues with how the tags are currently being used.**

The [gender](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) applies to all questions related to gender, including sexism, discrimination, being a minority, and transgender issues. The [lgbtq](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq) tag applies to questions relating to sexual orientation and gender identity. It would then be appropriate to use **both tags** for questions about being transgender in the workplace. Editing either of the tags to remove transgender topics would be needlessly restrictive, especially considering how many other tags have overlaps.